# Django- How do I select particular columns from a model?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have an array of columns. Like,

```
fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
# this values can be dynamic
```

I want the values of those columns from the User model.

I tried this.

```
User.objects.values(fields)
```

But it doesn't work. It provides a traceback.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

User.objects.values(*fields)
```